# Error When I Run My Python Code using sketchpy lib

Tags: python

The ERROR

```
UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable 'res' where it is not associated with a value
```

```
from sketchpy import canvas
obj = canvas.sketch_from_svg("23.svg")
obj.draw()
print(obj)
```

Comment: It's issue with `sketchpy ` Can attach complete traceback

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.